# How to pass content in TinyMCE's textarea to a PHP file directly instead of sending via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I build a simple webpage with embeded TinyMCE.

The HTML part:

```
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
<div id="main">
<div id="container_left">
        <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">            
</div>
<div id="show_right"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

The JavaScript part.

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    height: 250,
    plugins: [
        "code advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "code insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init keydown change', function (e) {
           document.getElementById('show_right').innerText = editor.getContent();
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Now I want to print content in the TinyMCE's editor, after you click the `submit` button.

The dump.php

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Why nothing  print by dump.php?
I can send info to the dump.php via AJAX method.
1.Remove `<form method="post" action="dump.php"></form>` in html part.
2.Add the following js code in the JavaScript part.

```
<script>
function send(){
    var data = tinyMCE.get('mytextarea').getContent();
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','dump.php',false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.send('data='+data);    
} 
ob = document.getElementById("submit");
ob.addEventListener("click",send);
</script>
```

I have tried that it can pass  content which I type in the `textarea` whose `id` is `mytextarea` to `dump.php` and `dump.php` can print the array properly.

My issue is how to pass content in TinyMCE's `textarea` to a PHP file directly instead of sending it via AJAX?
Do the work without AJAX.

Comment: Use `setup` config property. Take a look to my post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can send it without AJAX with an hidden `iframe` which has as `target` attribute the `name` value from `iframe`. The original page will not reload. The answer from your server will be loaded in hidden `iframe`. In that case, you have to set the `iframe` `display` to `none`.

```
<iframe name="server_answer" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="dump.php" target="server_answer">
    <div id="main">
    <div id="container_left">
        <textarea id="mytextarea" name="mytext"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">            
    </div>
    <div id="show_right"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For your `textarea` you have also to write some `name` as attribute, for example like `name="mytext"` because on the server side you want get the text, which will sended. And because you did not write this `name` you can not get it. In your AJAX solution you do it with `ajax.send('data='+data);`. In this case `data` is like the name of your `textarea`.

**For your PHP script:**

```
print($_POST["mytext"]); //mytext is name of textarea
```

**Alternative solution**

You could also display the submit form as a separate page inside the iframe, and when it gets submitted then the outer page will not reload. This solution does not use AJAX too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need iframe, just add this to your tinymce config to keep original textarea sync with the editor

```
tinymce.init({
selector: '#mytextarea',
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function () {
        editor.save();
    });
}
});
```

Quick and dirty poc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']): ?>
  <pre><?php print_r($_POST) ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
    <form method="post">
      <label for="mytitle">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="mytitle" name="title" value="">
      <textarea id="mytextarea" name="content"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you must name for textarea. And "dump.php" :

<?php

print_r ($_POST["**name_of_textarea**"]);

?>

Comment: `print_r($_POST) `can print the whole array.